# Getting apps/extensions icon File object to base64

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm using the [management](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management) API to get all my installed apps and extensions. I want to send this information to server.

Every app/extension has an `icon` array, that has `size` and `url`.
The `url` is something like `chrome://extension-icon/gmgpodcgeocidkeclglljo88jp9kclhhmmdacfo/32/0`.  I want to send it to my server in base64.

What I'm trying to do is something like:

```
var reader  = new FileReader();

reader.onloadend = function() {
   result = reader.result;
}

if (file) {
     reader.readAsDataURL(file);
} else {
    result = "";
}
```

Where `file` is a File object of the icon url. But I cannot find how to create an File object with this url format.

I've tried:

```
var fileUrlArray = ["chrome://extension-icon/gmgpodcgeocidkeclglljo88jp9kclhhmmdacfo/32/0"];
var file = new File(fileUrlArray, 'icon.png');
```

And as a result I got an absolutely wrong base64 string.

Any ideas about how to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: One extension cannot simply peek into another's files/pages/icons. Try [chrome.debugger API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger)

Comment: But why is there an "icon" property of installed extensions, apps, or themes?

Comment: And why not? Just 'cause :-)

Comment: Perhaps fetch: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: Why don't you send it as it is? `fetch(url, {method: post, body: blob})` base64 takes up ~3x more bandwidth and will take longer to read/decode/encode

Comment: Using fetch: `URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.` :/

Comment: But how would I get a blob from the icon directory?

Comment: See [Chrome extension can't get access to chrome://extension-icon](//stackoverflow.com/a/40483868)

Comment: Ok but how can I send it to my server, using base64 for example?